# EmberJS binding does not work

Tags: ember.js

I just started to learn Ember.js, and reading the doucmentation at http://emberjs.com/.
At the Binding section, I just copied&pasted following code, and executed it on Chrome browser. Binded data (App.husband.get('householdIncome')) always returned 'undefined'. Do you know why? I'd like to know why my code does not work.

----- HTML code ------

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/ember-0.9.6.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

----- app.js ------

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();
App.wife = Ember.Object.create({
  householdIncome: 80000
});

App.husband = Ember.Object.create({
  householdIncomeBinding: 'App.wife.householdIncome'
});

console.log(App.wife.get('householdIncome')); // 80000
console.log(App.husband.get('householdIncome'));// expected 80000
```

------ Result Output -----------

```
80000
undefined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put `Em.run.sync();` before the .get()s. The reason for this is that Ember's RunLoop, which connects bound properties, hasn't finished running. By using `Em.run.sync();`, you force the RunLoop to run to completion before any code that follows. This might seem like an inconvenience, but normally, you don't ever really need to call .get() so soon after declaring objects with bound properties, because the RunLoop will handle connecting those properties ultimately to the Handlebars templates which display those values properly. But in some cases, you need those properties to be bound immediately, in which case you use `Em.run.sync()`.

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edwG6/

Also, you'll notice a very similar example on http://emberjs.com in the first Bindings section. Note the comment that says `// Later, after Ember has resolved bindings...`

Comment: Hi Alexander, Thank you very much. Em.run.sync() solved the problem.